# Any idea how to get rid of these reddish spots on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The arrows show those reddish squares I want to get rid of:

[image]

Comment: Delete the trailing whitespace?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The reason I have not been able to find an answer is because I don't know exactly how to describe that part of the IDE except by showing in the picture. As you can see, there is that color that poors into the gaps of every line of space. I assume it is a color to indicate not just the tab spaces, but also spaced between lines of text.

Comment: Here is another picture of the problem. Doesn't look annoying to you those red areas, or is it just me?    https://i.imgur.com/ScWr0sY.png

Comment: I was convinced that the problem was coming from plug-in indent-rainbow, but I have not found any solution for this annoying problem.

Comment: Jonrsharpe, deleting those spaces are not an option or maybe I am not understanding your answer.